# Lost-Update and Two-Phase Locking (How dead-lock occurs?)

Tags: database, oracle, transactions, deadlock, acid

Can you please check whether my answer is acceptable for these questions? Question 1 is about lost-update and Question 2 is about 2PL ( How deadlock occurs? )

**QUESTION TITLE**
[image]

**QUESTION 1**

[image]

**My Answer for (Q1)**

Lost-Update Problem

**Reason:**

Expected final value for A will be 280 while B will be 240. But due to lost-update problem, these two respective values couldnt be achieved.

As for the transaction T1, the value A is being read at time t1 which is 160 and value B is being read at time t2 which is 60. During time t2, Transaction T2 begins, and value B is being read as well which is known as a dirty-read. Followed by time t4, the value B has been calculated in Transaction 1 and on time t6, value B has been partially committed which is 120 meanwhile, in Transaction T2 time t5, value B has been calculated as well which now holds 120 and is being partially committed as well. Lastly, value B which is 120 has been committed in Transaction 1 on time t7 and later followed by value B which is 120, committed in Transaction 2 on time t11. This is when Lost-Update problem occurs whereby the value B on Transaction 1 is overwritten by value B on Transaction T2.

**Versioning Approach** -->
Still unsure about this will update my answer here after i finish my studies! Apologies for this!

**QUESTION 2**

[image]

**My Answer for (Q2)** How deadlock occurs in 2PL

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**My explanation**

In Transaction T1 there are two locks being requested. During time t2, read-lock is being used on value A because value A is needed to read only and write-lock is being used on value B because value B is needed for modifying or writing data. Meanwhile, Transaction T2 begins and write-lock is being requested and notice that T1 has not yet unlock value B and this is when the write-lock in Transaction T2 Is not granted because value B is still being write-lock in Transaction T1 and this is known as **mutual exclusion situation** whereby operation in Transaction T2 will be waiting for Transaction T1 operation to finish, then value B will be unlocked and since only Transaction T2 is waiting on Transaction T1 and Transaction T1 isn't waiting for Transaction T2 then **there is no deadlock to occur**, Transaction T2 will just simply wait until Transaction T1 completes the transaction no matter how long Transaction T1 lasts. And as we can see at time t12 the write-lock on value B is being granted as soon as value A and value B is committed means the exclusive-lock on value B is usable as unlocking has been done on Transaction 1.